# Facebook SDK remove app permissions programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api, permissions

I'am working in an `iOS` application that requests user Facebook login with a list of permissions.

I can check if the user have declined some of the requested permission by this method
`[[[FBSession activeSession] permissions] isEqualToArrayOfStrings:permissions]` and remove the `session`.
But the problem is if the user tried to login again ,The `Facebook SDK` doesnt request for the `permissions` again it shows a view says

> "you have already authorized XXXXX "

And doest ask the user to accept the permissions he has declined before.
Because of this i need **revoke or delete** the user permissions from his Facebook account to be able to ask for `permissions` again ;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer in this link [Revoke Login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/permissions#permissions-revokinglogin)

```
[[[FBRequest alloc]initWithSession:[FBSession activeSession] graphPath:@"me/permissions" parameters:nil HTTPMethod:@"delete"] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    // Handling 
                 }];
```

Answer (score 0):

For swift version

```swift
let connection = GraphRequestConnection()
connection.add(GraphRequest(
    graphPath: "/me/permissions",
    parameters: [:],
    httpMethod: .delete
)) { httpResponse, result, error in 
// Handling
}
connection.start()
```